# Render a rotation grid of an object

Tags: rendering

Is there any way to automatically generate a rotation grid of an object like in these pictures in Blender?:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I'd like a way to control the exact increments of the rotation if possible

And maybe also use a full 360 rotation, instead of being limited to 90/180.

Any help will really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a small addon for you, that you can download here: https://github.com/Hilicot/Blender-Rotational-Grid

after installing it, you can tweak the settings in the Matrix Grid tab in the tool menu and press "create grid" while you have your object selected.

you can also modify that grid or delete it (but you always need to have the original object selected before pressing those buttons)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful add-on! Didn't expect something this cohesive!
https://i.imgur.com/qTDW4eA.png But I'm getting this error when installing the .zip file (downloaded through Github's "Download ZIP" button") in Blender's Add-on tab in the User Preferences menu. Am I doing something wrong? I also tried installing the .py file directly, but nothing happens that way.

Comment: I'm a dumbass, fixed it by updating to 2.80

Again thanks for the massive help. But one request, can you maybe add a way to get a more accurate non-ortho perspective of each object? Right now the angle gets less accurate (relative to the specification) the further away from the centre you get.

I'm thinking of maybe automatically creating a separate scene for each item/position of the grid, along with a camera pointing at them in the centre, then batch rendering all of the scenes, which then can be stitched together externally. 

I'll create a new question if this is out of scope.

Comment: yes, sorry, i made it for 2.80. As for the distortion, you just need to set your camera as ortographic, like in my screenshot, and play around with the scale as needed

Comment: Alright thanks. and sorry for the late reply, but there's another issue that's been bothering me. Right now how the program handles rotation is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/qd7hn3M.gifv
But what I'm trying to achieve is this: https://i.imgur.com/RudxlSs.gifv
Is there any way to make it work like the latter?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean: in your gifs you are using global vs local rotations, so if with "program" you mean Blender, you can switch to local transforms and you are fine, if you mean my addon, I would need more informations on the issue and how do you want it to work.

My addon deals with rotation by modifying the `delta_rotation_euler` properties of the objects (so their delta rotations), which are global

Comment: Strange, visually judging from my results, it seems that rotation is done locally. For example, look at the last row of the grid in this image https://i.imgur.com/XEs2d1b.png, it doesn't look like they're rotated globally.
So to further investigate, I did a manual rotation on the top row as a way to get some rough visual proof https://i.imgur.com/pS2GzxY.gifv, and as I expected it doesn't match up with what the bottom row looks like. This seems to suggest that it was rotated locally.
Or am I misunderstanding how this program generates the grid and rotation?

Comment: yes, I see what you mean: my addon rotates the objects around the x and z global axis, and if your rotate first on the x, or fist on the z, you get 2 different images. However this is how Blender (and 3D in general) works: just look at this picture https://ibb.co/qjr2Hpy.

Comment: I can invert the order of the rotation if you want, but mixing them up is not a great idea. If you want a different look for your grid, please build one manually how you like it and send it to me, you might need something totally different...

Comment: Ah, I think I'm starting to understand. So it's a matter of the order of rotation? Looking at the image again, the addon rotates the object on the X axis first, then the Z axis, like this: https://i.imgur.com/c911lxf.png https://i.imgur.com/Tzk21mD.png am I getting this right? So yeah, I'd greatly appreciate it if you can invert it somehow.
This is what my ideal grid should look like based on that specific params (I counted the degrees properly this time): https://i.imgur.com/Y18wxo2.png
But I'm not sure what you mean by mixing up and how it's a bad idea, can you elaborate

Comment: Also, to add more clarity, this is what my ideal rotation order should look like: https://i.imgur.com/XGGl7ZM.png https://i.imgur.com/vurabG0.png

Comment: @whatthe Done: I have created a "invert" checkbox that lets you switch the order.
You just need to download the addon again from the GitHub page

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! But it seems to be rotating along the incorrect axis (the Y and X axis instead of the Z and X axis?) https://i.imgur.com/619EITr.png
Compare to what my ideal grid should look like: https://i.imgur.com/Y18wxo2.png

Comment: I think I got it, finally ;P
I updated it again. This time I checked and it's the same: the grid you want is made with local transformations, I just had to change that

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It's working pretty good, though it behaves a bit strangely when it is inputted with negative values. But I managed to circumvent the issue by first rotating the object to the desired initial position, then apply the transforms to the mesh before generating the grid.
https://i.imgur.com/GxHlb6b.png
But there's one more final request I want to ask and I'm really sorry that I didn't bring this up earlier. But is there any way to extend the grid upwards? This is another format of grid that I want to generate: https://i.imgur.com/Zw0wHyA.png

Comment: I made a few changes to fix the negative values https://ibb.co/vPYNFWd. You still need to apply your eventual rotation though (I believe it's better this way).
To make the grid go up you can input a negative offset in the Row section, but your original object will always be in the corner. The reason for it it's just faster and easier coding (for instance if you have an even number of rows you need to move the original object, etc...), so for now you can just grab the whole grid and traslate it upwards manually

Comment: It works absolutely flawlessly https://i.imgur.com/NKlSiKS.png (I don't seem to need to apply any manual rotation this time though, but w/e)! Thank you so much for all of your extensive assistance and patience so far! Didn't expect this much help.

Comment: Don't worry, I had fun ahah